# I can't get return super().form_valid(form) to work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, forms, django-forms

**I have resolved my issue and provided my solution below.**

When I create or update a post the changes are saved to the sites database. But after clicking the submit button I get an error message.

```
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
```

I want to be redirected to the current URL. I thought the line of code `return super().form_valid(form)` implied that.

I could do `success_url = '/'`but I ideally don't want to be returned to the homepage.

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']

        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.author = self.request.user
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in models.py was wrong, I was missing indents.

My site runs fine with this code -

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content =  models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```